# How to test for BSD on GitHub actions?

Tags: github-actions, bsd

I'm working on a project that needs to work on both Linux/BSD and every once in a while a change is made that causes a regression for BSD.

How can I test BSD on GitHub actions?

Comment: You can use `macos-12` runner which has VirtualBox installed on it and use https://github.com/vmactions/freebsd-vm action to work with FreeBSD. Here's an [example](https://github.com/liquidaty/zsv/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L65-L80).

Comment: @Azeem now it works on `ubuntu-latest`.

Comment: @charlie137: It's good news. Thank you for sharing!

Comment: @charlie137: https://github.com/cross-platform-actions/action is also there.

Comment: @Azeem Oh, this is nice! Thanks! Everything I need in one neat action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[VM actions](https://github.com/vmactions)** for GitHub actions with BSD: Virtual machines based on MacOS. Supports FreeBSD, OpenBSD, NetBSD, Solaris and DragonFlyBSD.